# Gmail labels with new smart inbox categories - what are the new cannocial names for them

Tags: android, gmail

Since google added the option for the smart inbox categories (forums, social, updates etc) I've not worked out how to identify when a mail comes through to these accounts.

Does anyone know the label names for these new account

e.g. the old inbox was: ^i and priority inbox was: ^iim

I've not spotted any google docs on this yet.

Comment: I've found a couple so far: promotions: ^sq_ig_i_promo 
social: ^sq_ig_i_social. There also seems to be the following tags ^sq_ig_i_notification (maybe updates?), ^sq_ig_i_group (maybe forums?), ^sq_ig_i_personal (maybe personal?) It'd be great if anyone could confirm

Comment: After more investigation I can confirm the following label names: ^sq_ig_i_personal     Primary 
^sq_ig_i_social       Social 
^sq_ig_i_promo        Promotions
^sq_ig_i_notification Updates
^sq_ig_i_group        Forums

Comment: Anyone know if these are exposed via Gmail's IMAP?